# using vue-head with prerender-spa-plugin is causing title and meta tags to be displayed twice on netlify

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router, netlify

This issue only happens when live on netlify ( despite their prerender option turned off ), not while being served locally.

the live site shows :

```
<title>about | anonplayer about | anonplayer</title>
```

title and meta tags are set using the vue-head package like so

```
  head: {  
    title: {
      inner: "about | anonplayer",
      separator: ' ',
    }, ...
```

and this happens for all routes of my single page app and also to meta tags where there are two sets of the tags I intended to have.

looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ESKW.jpg)

I used the default prerender settings like so:

```
  config.plugins.push(new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
    // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
    staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // Required - Routes to render.
    routes: ['/', '/about'].concat(contracts.map(each => `/${each.abi}/${each.contract}`)),
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

was the same, but with Angular

in my case helped replacing *function this.meta.addTag()* with *this.meta.updateTag()*

so think it's not hosting issue)

Comment: cant see such an option with this package.

Comment: Wher did you replace that?