# Vue-head title is twice

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Basically I have exact same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407589/using-vue-head-with-prerender-spa-plugin-is-causing-title-and-meta-tags-to-be-di) but no one answer that question.

I have following code for title in my index component:

```
export default {
    head: {
        title: function () {
            return {
                inner: this.$options.filters.translate('yacht charter'),
                separator: ' ',
                id: 'indexTitle'
            }
        },
```

I'm also using prerender-spa-plugin. Title at first is once (when I use show code ctrl+U) but when javascript loads and execute, it double title.

This happen only to prerendered app.

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed it with changing 7th line in vue-head.js in node_modules directory from:

```
complement: window.document.title,
```

to

```
complement: '',
```